# What is the name of a linear combination that has coefficients that sum up to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Is there a special name for a linear combination where the coefficient add up to zero?

Comment: The qualifier "null-sum" is used in the theory of games. This applies to the coefficients, not to the linear combination.

Comment: In statistics, "contrast" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(statistics)

Comment: In linear algebra, such a vector would be orthogonal to the all-one vector. While there is (as far as I know) no special name for such a vector, this property is used in many cases (e.g. even or double even vectors in coding theory, describing properties of certain lattices,...).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).